# SELECT DISTINCT on one column (SQL Server 2005 or greater) using php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, distinct

I have tried the code provided here in stackoverflow, but i still get an error. can someone tell me where im mistaking? thank you! This is my code:

```
$allOrdersFromToday = $Microinvest->MSelectList('SELECT * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Acct ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber FROM Operations WHERE Date = "' . $todayDate . '" AND OperType = 2 ORDER BY Acct DESC) AS a', '*', 'a.RowNumber = 1');
```

which should output as:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Acct ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber
         FROM   Operations
         WHERE  Date = "' . $todayDate . '" AND OperType = 2 ORDER BY Acct DESC) AS a
WHERE   a.RowNumber = 1
```

but im getting an error... :(

> Warning: mssql_query(): message: Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'SELECT'. (severity 15) in /var/www/functions/MssqlLibry.php on line
>   29

Comment: Side Note: mssql functions are deprecated, you shouldn't really use them because you're prone to SQL Injection. Have a look at the PHP Drivers for Microsoft SQL Server: https://sqlsrvphp.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not support `order by` in subqueries, under most circumstances.  Try this:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM (SELECT o.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Acct ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber
      FROM Operations o
      WHERE  Date = "' . $todayDate . '" AND
             OperType = 2
     ) a
WHERE a.RowNumber = 1
ORDER BY a.Acct DESC;
```

In addition, you could have a problem because of the format of the date.  You should use parameterized queries rather than substituting values into strings.

Comment: im getting this error: Warning: mssql_query(): message: 'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name

Comment: What version of MS SQL are you using?  All currently supported versions support `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: im using SQL Server 2005

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express      9.00.2047.00
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      2000.085.1132.00 (xpsp.080413-0852)
Microsoft MSXML      2.6 3.0 4.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      8.0.6001.18702
Microsoft .NET Framework      2.0.50727.3655
Operating System      5.1.2600

Comment: It is documented as being available:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.90).aspx.  Perhaps you have a compatibility level set on your database that removes the functionality.